Android SQLite hangs with no error or success with `DELETE FROM ${tableName}` command
I have a SQLite DB for an android expo react native app, using package expo-sqlite 13.2.2. I am trying to run a function that will clear all the data out of the database so that a user can restore data from a backup, but on executing the first command the entire thing hangs. I have console.log statements in my success callback and my failure callback, but neither is executed. It just hangs up with no feedback.
It appears that this results in a DB lock, because no reads or writes can occur from the rest of the app after an unsuccessful data clear. I have log statements all over the place confirming that no other part of my function executes after the DELETE FROM
I am completely sure that the table name matches a real table name. I have tried deleting a single table that does not have any foreign key relations with any other table in my DB, but I get the same result. There are about 7 tables in my TABLE_NAMES enum, by the way
Another weird thing is that my Promise.all apparently resolves just fine, despite my code never executing the console.log before the resolve or the reject statements.
The code that fails:
export function clearAllData() {
    const promiseArray : Promise<void>[] = [];

    // avoid foreign key constraint failures
    const tableNamesReverse = [...Object.values(TABLE_NAMES)].reverse();

    for (const tableName of tableNamesReverse) {
        promiseArray.push(
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                database.transaction((tx) => {
                    console.log(`DELETE FROM ${tableName}`)
                    tx.executeSql(
                        `DELETE FROM ${tableName}`,
                        [],
                        (_, result) => {
                            console.log(`Deleted table ${tableName}`)
                            resolve();
                        },
                        (_, err) => { 
                            console.log(err);
                            reject();
                            return true;
                        }
                    );
                });
            })
        )
    }
    return Promise.all(promiseArray);
}

All I get in my console:
 LOG  clearing all data!  // StackOverlow NOTE: This is from the line that calls the above method
 LOG  DELETE FROM migrations

I've also tried simplifying this to just await one Promise in the above function, like below, but it still does not get to either the success callback or the failure callback:
export async function clearAllData() {
    await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        database.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(
                `DELETE FROM ${TABLE_NAMES.Migrations}`,
                [],
                (_, result) => {
                    console.log(`Deleted table ${TABLE_NAMES.Migrations}`)
                    resolve();
                },
                (_, err) => { 
                    console.log(err);
                    reject();
                    return true;
                }
            );
        });
    });
    return;
}


I'm having the same issue in my Expo app.  Works fine in iOS, but the compiled Android code hangs on a "delete from tablename" command.  No error.  Just stops.
I had just upgraded to Expo 50, with expo-sqlite version 13.4.0.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
